# why does my geolocation it is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, geopy, nominatim

The duty of my function is to calculate the distance from my business to any address (at the end (print fucntion) I put an example of an address)). I don´t know why it is not working, it says something about traceback error.

The first part of my function, converts from address to coordinates.
The second part calculate the distance.

**THIS IS THE CODE**

```
import math
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

def Distancia(direccion_domicilio):
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
    location = geolocator.geocode(direccion_domicilio)
    latylon=(location.latitude, location.longitude)


    rad=math.pi/180
    dif_lat = 20.6072848-(latylon[0])
    dif_long = -103.4160099-(latylon[1])
    radio=6372.795477598
    a=(math.sin(rad*dif_lat/2))**2 + math.cos(rad*location.latitud)*math.cos(rad*20.6072848)*(math.sin(rad*dif_long/2)**2)
    distancia=2*radio*math.asin(math.sqrt(a))
    return distancia

print(Distancia("Avenida Guadalupe, Real Guadalupe, Jardines de Chapalita, Zapopan, Jalisco, 45030, México"))
```

**THIS IS THE ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1317, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1229, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 956, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 1392, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1029: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 344, in _call_geocoder
    page = requester(req, timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1360, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1319, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error _ssl.c:1029: The handshake operation timed out>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Python programas\Ejercicios extras\PROYECTOdistancia.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(Distancia("Avenida Guadalupe, Real Guadalupe, Jardines de Chapalita, Zapopan, Jalisco, 45030, México"))
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Documents\Python programas\Ejercicios extras\PROYECTOdistancia.py", line 6, in Distancia
    location = geolocator.geocode(direccion_domicilio)
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\osm.py", line 307, in geocode
    self._call_geocoder(url, timeout=timeout), exactly_one
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\base.py", line 367, in _call_geocoder
    raise GeocoderTimedOut('Service timed out')
geopy.exc.GeocoderTimedOut: Service timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not perform a whole installation process. Traceback tells you what is happening. It says that there is a problem with SSL certificate. `geopy` library retrieves data from web (Nomitatiom in your case).
Take a look at this documentation: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.options and option called `default_ssl_context`.
You should use this code at the beginning of yours code (from the above documentation):

- to use SSL use:

```
    import ssl
    import certifi
    import geopy.geocoders
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
    geopy.geocoders.options.default_ssl_context = ctx
```

- to disable SSL (not recommended, may not even work for some geo providers):

```
    import ssl
    import geopy.geocoders
    ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
    ctx.check_hostname = False
    ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    geopy.geocoders.options.default_ssl_context = ctx
```